# lua C api: How to traverse a table with no possibility of lua_error / lua panic?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, error-handling, lua

In the lua 5.2 manual they have [some documentation](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_next) regarding `lua_next`, the function used to iterate over a table.

> A typical traversal looks like this:

```
 /* table is in the stack at index 't' */
 lua_pushnil(L);  /* first key */
 while (lua_next(L, t) != 0) {
   /* uses 'key' (at index -2) and 'value' (at index -1) */
   printf("%s - %s\n",
          lua_typename(L, lua_type(L, -2)),
          lua_typename(L, lua_type(L, -1)));
   /* removes 'value'; keeps 'key' for next iteration */
   lua_pop(L, 1);
 }
```

According to the manual, none of the C api calls in this example can cause a lua error (`lua_type`, `lua_typename`, `lua_pushnil`, `lua_pop`) EXCEPT for `lua_next`.

As I understand, `lua_next` can only cause an error in the case that it fails to allocate memory, so this is really only an issue in programs in which you hope to recover from memory allocation failures.

However, suppose that I am writing such a program. Is there a way that I can avoid putting the above iteration code in a protected call if I want to be able to recover from such an error?

As I understand, the `lua_next` should not actually be copying anything. The memory on the stack is already allocated and assigning atomic values to a stack position does not cause lua to allocate more memory. In the case of strings, lua is copy-on-write. In the case of reference values, it just increments a reference counter and doesn't need a dynamic allocation.

Suppose I put `lua_checkstack(L, 2)` first to ensure that there is stack space for the two entries (`key` and `value`). Is that enough to guarantee that I won't have a lua error, and so can avoid putting this in a protected context? (Forgetting what the manual says.) What exactly are the dynamic allocations that lua needs to do here?

Comment: The identifier: `[-1, +(2|0), e]` says that the function may throw errors. Check the source: https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lapi.c.html#lua_next

Comment: Right, so this is the meat of it: https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/ltable.c.html#luaH_next What in here is potentially causing a dynamic allocation? To my knowledge, `lua_next` cannot trigger metamethod lookup.

Comment: Does `lua_next` only produce an error if I start it off with a bad key or something? I mean clearly there is an error call in here: https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/ltable.c.html#findindex

Comment: There are also possible errors raised in https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lapi.c.html#index2addr

Comment: I see, but so long as there actually is a table I think none of that will throw

Comment: AFAICS, `findindex` is the only place where `lua_next` can raise an error. And that should only happen when you pass in a key that's not in the table, or when you modify the table while iterating. Remember that `lua_tostring`/`lua_tonumber`/`lua_isnumber` may change the type of a value on the stack (which could then result in a non-existent key). Anyway, why not use `lua_pcall` to be safe?!

Comment: I guess I find the "cpcall" idiom to be ugly. But now that has made me think that I just need a generic implementation so that it doesn't require so much boilerplate. Anyways I think it's a reasonable question, you don't want to make more pcall than necessary. Before this I thought there was no way to inspect a table at all really if you are in "out of memory", but now I have learned that there is

Comment: @siffiejoe: If I just put a `pcall` everywhere I wasn't sure then I would have a very large number of `pcall`. This question is about whether I actually need those `pcall` in a particular case I guess.

Comment: @ChrisBeck: You only need to use pcall in places where you want to do something *immediately* when an error is raised. That's not that often. Alternatively, you can put a userdata with a finalizer on the Lua stack and let the GC call it unless you disarm it first in the no-error case.

Comment: @siffiejoe: It depends on what exactly you are doing in the C api. If you are just writing callbacks that you push to lua, then its okay for them to signal lua errors -- lua itself will catch them and signal them to the script as an error in the callback function. But when there is no callback, when you are just writing C api calls from your application to control the VM, lua error means that the program is terminated -- `lua_panic` follows, and unless you do squirrelly things with the panic handler thats it. So knowing exactly what commands can error in what cases matters alot to me.

Comment: Since any Lua function call can raise a memory error, omitting the initial `lua_pcall`/`lua_cpcall` is asking for trouble.